Does the ship of Theseus have any impact on our perspective of life and death?
From my perspective, The ship of Theseus i.e., Theseus's paradox gives us a thought experiment of the preservation of identity.
One thing that intuitively follows to me is the fact that this thought experiment perfectly fits within the context of a human being or any being for that fact.
Let us say in a distant future, people start replacing their body parts using cyborglike materials enough so that they have no identifiable organic parts would this still maintain the fact that they are humans or would they be robots ,now, is this a linguistic separation or is there a more meaningful ontological separation?
Another one that follows is that humans are basically an arrangement of organic atoms and molecules at a fundamental level but all these organic atoms and molecules come from already existing within the environment or things that had existed. One way I can explain this is that the carbon atoms in the carbon based diet we eat, and shortly after becomes a part of the atomic constituent of our body might contain carbon atoms from say, Aristotle's or Socrates's bodies or even a mix and match of carbon atoms from several different beings. So through the light of Theseus's paradox what does that make any human (more so looking at a human being as an emergent property from it's building blocks), applying Theseus's paradox are we constantly different because our body must go through killing, replacing and removing cells which is alike to a continual process of replacing the parts of Theseus's ship, so through this light who am I and who is anyone else for that matter, does the essence of our identity lie in the arrangement of the building blocks, but if so then doesn't this solve Theseus's paradox by stating that if the arrangement of whatever parts of the ship is maintained then the ship is still the same ship regardless of its parts.
If one places importance on the parts (for thought experimental purpose) and thus approaches identity from the constituents then, does that mean everyone that ever was still exists in the modern time because the parts that make them are still here. I know there are lots of conflation of the meaning of words and some categorical errors, so my apologies. I just had this weird intuition for a long time and just had to blurt it out and possibly have any form of engagement.
Does the ship of Theseus have any impact on our perspective of life and death?

Asking for users' thoughts and perspectives is off-topic here. That the ship of Theseus is a paradigm for identity over time is widely recognized in the literature, see SEP, Diachronic Identity Puzzles. The effect of replacement and/or exchange of body parts on persistence of human identity in particular is also discussed there at length, see SEP, Personal Identity.

@Conifold Yes but there is nothing within academic entries that ties personal identity, the ship of Theseus and life & death so, I don't know.

A similar, related question could be asked about replicating the mind.in a computer...and if it changes the answer if the mind doesn't realize it's in a computer.

I am no expert on eastern philosophy, but don't some eastern thinkers resolve this by saying the self is merely an illusion, and the person we are NOW is in fact NOT the same as it was moments ago? Maybe someone better versed than me can provide this perspective.

@kutschkem the basic idea is that the concept of an enduring self is misleading. It's the wrong way to think of oneself or other selves. Digging further to understand why it is incorrect is a waste of effort, just "fuhget about it"

I don't think the cyborg replacement thing fits with the Ship of Theseus idea. The point of the ship is to keep it in the original condition as much as possible. That cyborg idea is like slowly replacing worn wooden ship parts with metal ones.

@OwenReynolds exactly, isn't the whole narrative the replacement of the old materials of the ship with new ones.

My concept of continuing Identity is a World Line.

@ScottRowe could you possibly say more about it, please.

See my Answer. Also, in general, we know something is the same one because all along we could keep saying, "it's still the same one." Anything beyond that seems like speculation or question-begging. Same = hasn't been swapped out from under me. Done.


Does the ship of Theseus have any impact on our perspective of life and death?

No.
The Ship of Theseus is a general observation about how larger entities are made up of smaller entities, and that identity is (quite obviously) actually more complicated than just throwing all constituents onto a big heap. The structural relationship between components matter; and that is the same between ships and humans.
In addition, the aspect of time in regards to identity makes the discussion so much more complicated. This is not helped by the fact that we don't even have a commonly accepted understanding what time even is.
Unless you are talking about the elementary particles, everything is subject to the Ship of Theseus confusion. The concept is much too pervasive to have any particular influence on any particular question (i.e. "What is death?").
On the other hand, identity, especially in humans (with the additional complexity of psychological identity, and especially the feeling of consciousness, as contrasted to an inanimate object like a ship), is a vastly complex topic, which is in no small parts very likely due to topics like consciousness or dualism being very much still up for opinion. They are called "hard" for a reason. Just imagine - if we knew for sure whether we are dual or non-dual entities (i.e. with a non-physical component a.k.a. soul; or purely physical), the discussion would very likely become very much simpler.
Finally, at least judging by SEP's article on Death, there seem to be quite a few interesting philosophical topics surrounding it, but nobody really seems to care about something akin to the Theseus aspects, regarding Death.

"They are called 'hard' for a reason" - the reason being that people latched onto supernatural beliefs about consciousness millennia before we knew much about how brains actually work or came about, and people built entire worldviews around that, which carries strong emotional appeal. If it weren't for all of that, and people were just raised with some understanding of the current scientific knowledge of neuroscience and evolution, with a healthy amount of critical thinking, then I'd expect much fewer people to consider it a "hard" problem.

@NotThatGuy but that isn't the proper progress of knowledge and also what we knew earlier still persists within the Scientific framework that lets us understand the conscious; psychology and biology is as much philosophy as is physics. Even with our current understanding the problem would still persist and wouldn't be eradicated. There would have been an epistemological flaw if we had the scientific knowledge without proper progression.

From a strictly physical point of view, a key difference between a human body and the ship, whose parts are replaced one by one, is that all the cells in a human body are linked together through the same individual DNA cell line.  Every cell descends from it (except in the case of organ transplants, for example).  In contrast, the original boards in the ship did not necessarily have any instrinsically unifying factor, and certainly not on such an essential level.
However, I think your question raises a deeper point, which is our intuition that we as humans are more than a mere physical collection of DNA-related cells.  Someone who loses a limb in a war does not become only 90% of what he was as a human.  Maybe he has lost 10% of his body, but he is still 100% a human being, whether he decides to get a synthetic replacement or not.  I imagine we would agree on that point.  And if we do, then the Bible's portrayal of man as essentially spiritual and clothed in physical makes more sense; and Ecclesiastes 12:7 would accurately portray death as a dissolution of the present physical "clothing," and an extraction of the essential spiritual soul: "Then shall the dust return to the earth as it was: and the spirit shall return unto God who gave it."

+1 What a great answer that is supported by Scripture. Thank you, my brother in Christ

You said, "DNA...such an essential level" Can you explain why you think that DNA is an "essential" part of our identity? You said, "except in the case of organ transplants." Can you explain why an exception should be made in that case? Why is my DNA an essential part of my identity, but not essential in any part of my body that our current medical technology is able to replace? The "Ship of Theseus" argument depends on replacing all of the parts, one-by-one. If we could replace all of the parts, and if DNA is not important in parts that can be replaced, then how is DNA important at all?

Not sure how DNA relation gets you anywhere... unless you appeal to some vague spiritual interconnectedness thing, but then that isn't "from a strictly physical point of view". From a strictly physical point of view, any linkage between cells needs to correspond to some physical thing for it to exist. Also, intuition is often wrong, and not everyone shares your intuition. My intuition, for example, can't make any sense of consciousness or will (or anything else) existing outside of the physical, and that intuition is supported by e.g. epistemology (a lack of evidence) and neuroscience.

Your losing a leg argument is kinda weird - there is certainly physically less of a person who lost a leg, but how we define "humanness" has more to do with personality / consciousness (brains), not limbs. People with neurodegenerative diseases are commonly described as e.g. being a shell of their former selves or losing who they are. We don't think of these people as "less human" (humanists don't, at least - plenty of other people do). But we do think of them having lost a part of themselves and who they are, "as a human", which seems contrary to your point.

If we interpret reality in certain ways, we can probably also make things with Lord of the Rings make more sense, but that doesn't really tell us much. We're still waiting for someone to demonstrate that the Bible is a reliable source of information, instead of e.g. history that's been mythologised with the addition of fabricated details (which is not exactly unheard of).

@SolomonSlow Maybe I could have been clearer, I mentioned transplants simply as an exception to my "all cells" comment, since they have cells too, but from a different DNA line; but my thought process went no deeper than that with the comment.  :)  The individually unique unifier of DNA in cells has no counterpart in the boards of the ship analogy.  But I wouldn't say our DNA is essential to our identity; maybe essential to our present physical identity, but I believe the present physical is more accidental than essential, since it can be changed out (e.g., II Corinthians 5:1-4).

In a brain transplant, you want to be the donor, not the recipient.

@ScottRowe Yes, okay. But, I don't see how that is a relevant comment to what he is talking about?

@Howwhye he was talking about losing a limb not making you less of a person. But without your brain, you wouldn't be you. So losing just a kilo would be quite significant there.

@ScottRowe Ha, I see what you mean, humorous and interesting insight.

It is not the case that every cell in your body has the same DNA. Different lineages of cells in a single healthy person have different mutations. https://www.nytimes.com/2018/05/21/science/mosaicism-dna-genome-cancer.html Also there is mosaicism where this variation is more pronounced. Also there are identical twins who have very similar DNA despite being different people.

@causative Good points.  That's why I worded it in the answer as being from the same individual DNA cell line, as opposed to having identical DNA. The twins is an especially interesting point I hadn't thought of.

No
I give you a counterexample.
My mother recently passed away. Apart from very minor changes her body was the same from the instant before her death to the instant immediately after; yet she was no longer a human being.

First off, I am really sorry to hear that.

It only takes a few minor changes in the right place to turn a floating ship into a sinking ship.

Death is often not an "instant". It's a process. Death is commonly thought of as when the heart stops, but many hearts have been successfully restarted or transplanted. Death also involves the ceasing of other processes in one's body, most significantly in one's brain - if brain activity ceases, that's typically considered something one can't be resuscitated from. But even brain activity ceasing is itself a process that doesn't happen in an instant. Basically what I'm saying is that this doesn't seem like a counter-example. If anything, it's supporting evidence.

If someone gets an artificial leg or gets a heart transplant, we'd still consider them the "same" person.
The reason for this is probably less about the ship of Theseus and more about us considering human identity to be about personality / consciousness (brains), instead of other body parts.
Now one could ask the question about brains: if you "upload" your brain to a computer (if that's ever possible), would that be "you"? If we create an exact biological copy of you, would that be "you"? Does it make a difference if the "original you" keeps living or dies in the process (or dies soon after)?
Although I suspect the answers one gives to these questions would come down to whatever one already believes about consciousness:

For a physicalist who believes that consciousness reduces to brain activity, one might also suppose an understanding that identity, categorisation and definitions are fuzzy concepts we made up, which don't always conform to how reality actually works. Through the natural progressing of time, you do quite literally become a different person as your brain changes, as brain cells are replaced and as they change as a result of your experiences (and also as a result of e.g. neurodegenerative diseases).
There isn't really an issue with saying there could (theoretically) be 2 "you"s, who think in the exact same way (but they would deviate from one another as a result of different experiences). You could say the original is the "real" you, or you could say they are all equally "real" - which option we go for is probably more about pragmatism, while the underlying facts are the same either way.

For a dualist who believes that consciousness exists separately from the brain, they'd probably maintain that any copy of you would not be conscious, or they might take a view similar to physicalism of a new identical consciousness popping up (there are a few different dualist views).


The above isn't exactly the ship of Theseus, but it's probably close enough: if you slowly replace parts of the brain, a physicalist would say the consciousness would probably continue as normal, assuming the replacement is functionally identical, and assuming there wasn't some problematic interruption that caused brain cells to die. A dualist might say the same (there's no need for a second consciousness, so it's less of an issue), or they could say you'd slowly lose parts of your consciousness.
So no, I don't think the ship of Theseus makes much of an impact on how we think about this.
Side note: The whole uploading/cloning thing could be a useful train of thought (when compared to the gaps in consciousness due to sleeping or anesthesia) for dealing with one's fear of death under physicalism.

Gaps in consciousness don't bother me. It's like walking away from the Ship and coming back into view of it. I don't have to camp out on it to be sure it's the same ship.

+1 A great insight, lowkey an approach to people facing their fears if they have thanatophobia.

The Ship of Theseus is a thought experiment. What you take from it, depends on your own processes of consideration of it.
David Chalmers has a very similar thought experiment he calls 'Fading Qualia' where he imagines a human brain being replaced with computer parts neuron by neuron. In this paper Absent qualia, fading qualia, dancing qualia (PhilPapers link). So there it's being used in a modern discourse about the nature of subjectivity.
From computing we have this idea of 'substrate independence', where a chunk of code or a programme can be instantiated or run on any computer. 'Identity' there becomes about function, what the code does, because it's so easy to make copies. This is the extreme end of where the Ship of Theseus can take you, and is an issue for mind uploading. For the boat though, structure and parts-coordination alone doesn't feel like enough, we would distinguish a copy from an original. But what if we literally couldn't tell them apart?
That is actually the case with fundamental particles, where they take on specific properties because they can swap when we aren't looking and we have no way to know.
This discourse on identity and materiality is used in Buddhist thought, to show that all models of identity are insufficient - indeed really grasping that in a deep way seems to be what Awakening is about. Nagarjuna has a nice summary of this:

"To think ‘it is,’ is eternalism, To think ‘it is not,’ is nihilism:
Being and non-being, The wise cling not to either."

In the Mahayana tradition they have this idea that part of our mind has a 'substrate independent' quality, and interacts with a domain they call the Alayavijnana (Wikipedia link), or 'storehouse-consciousness. This bears comparison to the 'memesphere', the domain of ideas that can replicate themselves. And, it's the Mahayana picture of how rebirth works, and karma propagates.
So certainly this Ship thought experiment can impact how we see life and death. And subjectivity, the nature of information and embodiment, and even spiritual practice. But I would say, avoid thinking 'It means this', instead do your own contemplating, investigating your own intuitions about identity and what the thought-experiment or related ones mean for them. Like that, we might even arrive at understanding the true nature of things.

+1 Truly what a great answer. I wasn't asking as to what it means because I realize it is a thought experiment you can individually interact with and there are a numerous amounts of takes but rather I asked if anyone of those takes could be interpreted through the light of life and death. I just wanted to know if anyone had similar takes and the process of arriving at such a take and my intuition had some similarities with others, that is all.


applying Theseus's paradox are we constantly different because our
body must go through killing, replacing and removing cells which is
alike to a continual process of replacing the parts of Theseus's ship,
so through this light who am I and who is anyone else for that matter,
does the essence of our identity lie in the arrangement of the
building blocks, but if so then doesn't this solve Theseus's paradox
by stating that if the arrangement of whatever parts of the ship is
maintained then the ship is still the same ship regardless of its
parts.

One might attempt to answer this by asking how we might measure identity, and then also asking how much of an identity each of the individual building blocks have.
In physics all particles of the same type are identical.  That is to say, one electron functionally indistinguishable from another one.
In chemistry it's the same for atoms or other chemical compounds.  All water molecules, for example, are functionally identical.
With respect to those types of building blocks, in classical mechanics, there still is some sense of identity in that particles of the same type can have different state (position, velocity, orientation, etc.).  But if we were to substitute one particle for another and put it in the same state, we wouldn't be able to tell they were different ones.
So, in that sense one might argue that even if your material is constantly changing you are functionally identical to your prior self.  That is, you are a process, not a material.
I think that answer may get past arguments along the lines of "there is only a small difference between a living and dead person".  If the small difference disrupts the process so you are no longer alive, then the material is no longer you.

+1 What a really great answer, humans are a process not a material is an interesting and accurate take.

You lost me at "functionally identical to your prior self". The natural changes that happen to our cells end up with something that isn't functionally identical. Well, it's functionally similar on a high level (your limbs typically keep functioning), and similar enough on a moment to moment basis, but in the longer term, you might lose or gain fat, muscle, bone density, etc., and for our brains in particular, every new experience results in some small changes to the brain.

@NotThatGuy I wouldn't get hung up on the word "identical" here.  You can go with "very very similar" if that works better for you.  You may also wish to constrain which parts of that functionality you consider essential to identity, and which ones don't matter.

One way to cut the Gordian Knot of identity is with the math / physics concept of a "world line". Applied to a particle, which in every sense is not unique or identifiable, it says that a single thing tracks through spacetime with no breaks and separate from every other thing (since two particles cannot occupy the same location).
Simply: if you keep your eye on the ball, or in some other way have a means to track it over time, you know definitely that it is the same ball. The picture is a curving line in spacetime. That's your identity. Now we just need to track everyone from cradle to grave and we can get rid of those tiresome National Identity Numbers! You are whom you say if I can follow the thread back to your birth. It's like using a secure ledger to hold financial transactions. Identity = provenance.


through this light who am I and who is anyone else for that matter, does the essence of our identity lie in the arrangement of the building blocks,

Yes to that.

but if so then doesn't this solve Theseus's paradox by stating that if the arrangement of whatever parts of the ship is maintained then the ship is still the same ship regardless of its parts.

It would seem so, when you include details about all components, their states, characteristics, properties.  Each nerve cell has a resting state and a firing state and a recovery time, as an example... and at any given moment, many many are in each state, energy and reaction levels.  We are more than "just" the bui8lding blocks... we are also their unique and specific and momentary arrangement.

If one places importance on the parts and thus approaches identity from the constituents then,

Um-hmm.  Let's do that.

does that mean everyone that ever was still exists in the modern time because the parts that make them are still here

No.  The specific and unique and momentary arrangements that composed a past individual, does not any longer exist anywhere as a functioning system.
Consider a characteristic of water.  By considering the length of time that dinosaurs wondered the Earth, and the numbers of them, and the quantity of water they would consume... it can be calculated and confidently concluded that the average drop of water passed through a dinosaur and got pissed out somewhere about 60 times.  Per molecule.
60 times, each water molecule has been temporarily part of a dinosaur.
It is not possible to consider a water molecule to be simultaneously part of 60 different entities.  Would it be reasonable to think of those 60 dinosaurs existing all at once, when there ain't enough water to make them all?
Nope.
The existence of the parts is not the same as the existence of what those parts could be if specifically processed and arranged and assembled.
Logically. I suggest.

So, in regards to time, taking a slice of time and observing all the properties and the arrangement and even the instantaneous activation of neural networks and recreating the momentary state of every activation, would that not technically be an already embedded property of the building blocks. We could take a building block as a stimulated nerve or an unstimulated nerve and thus we could properly at least recreate a time slice of a functioning human.
